# Can I have 2 before inside 1 describe using Mocha?

Tags: javascript, automation, mocha.js, hook, webdriver-io

I have a describe for all test cases of one app page. I have a context that includes all positive test cases and then a context inside it to include all negative test cases. Before all test cases I have one before that includes the login. I want to know that I can add another before for the negative test cases.

Example:

```
describe('X page', function (){
  context('As a user', function (){
    before(function(){
      login goes here
    });
    it('Test case 1', function (){
      test case implementation goes here
    });
    it('Test case 2', function (){
      test case implementation goes here
    });
    context('Negative tests', function (){
      before(function(){
        negative tests precondition goes here
      });
      it('Test case 1', function (){
        test case implementation goes here
      });
      it('Test case 2', function (){
        test case implementation goes here
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Can that second before go there?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. The `before` hooks in outer `describe` are executed before those in the inner `describe`. And if you have multiple `before` hooks in the same callback to `describe`, they are executed in the order they appear. (Note that `describe` is a synonym for `context`: Mocha assigns the same function to both.)